# Unit tests with Rust

Tags: rust

I have created a small maths library with a directory structure

mathslib -> `src` -> `lib.rs` -> conversions / stats / trig / bases

All of the modules are declared as being `pub` and the functions also as `pub`.

I've written the following test for just one function, but when I run `cargo test`, I'm met with an error that the function can't be resolved (E0425).

```
extern crate MathsLib;

use MathsLib::Conversions::Temperature;

#[cfg(test)]
mod TemperatureTests {
    #[test]
    fn test_kelvin_to_celcius_pass() {
         let calc = kelvin_to_celcius(14.5);
         assert_eq!(calc.0, true);
    }

    #[test]
    #[should_panic(expected = "assertion failed")]
    fn test_kelvin_to_celcius_fail() {
         let calc = kelvin_to_celcius(-4f32);
         assert_eq!(calc.0,true);
    }
}
```

From what I can see from the docs, this should be fine - but it's obviously not.

The function in question looks like this

```
pub fn kelvin_to_celcius(k: f32) -> (bool, f32)
{
    if k < 0f32
    {
        return (false, k);
    }
    else
    {
        return (true, k - 273.15);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a full example including the actual error message?

Answer (score 2):

Your functions aren't in scope.

Assuming your module layout is like this:

```
pub fn kelvin_to_celcius(k: f32) -> (bool, f32)
{
    if k < 0f32
    {
        return (false, k);
    }
    else
    {
        return (true, k - 273.15);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod TemperatureTests {
    ...
}
```

Then you'll need to bring the function into scope for your test module. The idiomatic way to do this is like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod TemperatureTests { 
    use super::*; // <--- use everything declared in the parent module
    ...
}
```

This allows everything in the enclosing module to be used in your test module without any qualifiers.

Alternatively, you would be able to change your calls for the method to this:

```
let calc = super::kelvin_to_celcius(-4f32); // <-- note, "super" .. you want to go into the outer scope to find the method
 assert_eq!(calc.0,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`use MathsLib::Conversions::Temperature;` adds the `Temperature` symbol to the module's scope, but it doesn't add any of the symbols in the `Temperature` module. If you want to do that, you need to write this instead:

```
use MathsLib::Conversions::Temperature::*;
```